# Execute simple FQL query with spring-social-facebook in java

Tags: java, facebook, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I would appreciate little help with spring-social-facebook library implementation. I am trying to execute FQL query but facebook sends me empty result. If I execute same query in Facebook Graph API Explorer it works like a charm. I have all permissions checked. My code is like this:

```
private static final String FQL_GET_FRIENDS = "SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";

Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(token);
List<Reference> references = facebook.userOperations().search(FQL_GET_FRIENDS);
```

Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. This worked for me:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        parameters.set("q", FQL_GET_FRIENDS);
Map<String, Object> resultSet = (Map<String, Object>) facebookTemplate
                .fetchObject("fql", Map.class, parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had done same via a simple HTTP Get Request to "faceBookURL" with a valid token with sufficient permissions, you could use this ::

```
private static String STR_FACEBOOK_FQL_URL = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=";
private static String STR_FACEBOOK_RETURN_FORMAT = "&format=json";
private static String STR_FACEBOOK_ENCODE_FORMAT = "UTF-8";
private static String STR_FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN = "&access_token=";

private static final String FQL_GET_FRIENDS = "SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";

String encodedQuery = URLEncoder.encode(FQL_GET_FRIENDS, STR_FACEBOOK_ENCODE_FORMAT);
String faceBookURL = STR_FACEBOOK_FQL_URL + encodedQuery + STR_FACEBOOK_RETURN_FORMAT
        + STR_FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN + token;
```